# Printing Employee and Salary from parallel array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The program will determine what salary is the highest and print that out along with the name of the employee who has that salary figure.

I need to make a list for employee and another list for salary. I can find the lowest/highest salary and print it out but I don't know how to print out that corresponding employee. What makes this hard is that we're only on chapter 6, and we can only use what we've learned so far. So we can't use a lot of the built-in functions Python has to offer (we haven't even covered the append() method so I had to use another way to add to the list..) max and min are also not allowed.

```
amount = int(input("How many employees?: "))
if amount <= 0:
    print("You cannot have 0 or less.")
name = []
salary = []
length = len(salary)
mini = 200000
maxi = 0
combined = (name, salary)

for i in range(1, amount + 1):
    employee = input("What is the employee's name?: ")
    name += [employee]
    earned = int(input("How much is the salary? It cannot be less than 0 or over $200,000: "))
    while earned <= 0 or earned >= 200000:
        earned = int(input("How much is the salary? It cannot be less than 0 or over $200,000: "))

        mini = earned
        maxi = earned
   salary += [earned]
   total += earned
   if earned < mini:
       mini = earned
   if earned > maxi:
       maxi = earned
```

Comment: `length = len(salary)` is *always* going to be `0`, and stay `0`.

Comment: `mini` and `maxi` are only going to be set initially if the user entered an *incorrect* value for `earned`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters see "We haven't even covered the append() method so I had to use another way to add to the list." , whether or not that's sensible is another question...

Comment: Ah, missed that part. Oh, the humanity, to have to limit yourself to the strict letter of the book? Real life doesn't work that way, you use what you can..

Comment: Have fixed what I think are various bugs in the version posted below, though I haven't run it so do check. Also the `mini = earned` line is surely a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the indices as follows

```
amount = int(input("How many employees?: "))
if amount <= 0:
    print("You cannot have 0 or less.")
name = []
salary = []
length = len(salary)
MAX_SALARY = 200000
mini = MAX_SALARY + 1
maxi = -1
mini_idx = -1
maxi_idx = -1

for i in range(amount):
    employee = input("What is the employee's name?: ")
    name += [employee]
    earned = -1
    while earned >= 0 and earned <= MAX_SALARY:
        earned = int(input("How much is the salary? It cannot be less than 0 or over $200,000: "))
    salary += [earned]
    total += earned
    if earned < mini:
        mini = earned
        mini_idx = i
    if earned > maxi:
        maxi = earned
        maxi_idx = i
```

Then the values you want are given by

```
salary[mini_idx]
name[mini_idx]
salary[maxi_idx]
name[maxi_idx]
```

Comment: the code does almost the same thing as before, it will print the max and min salary but it does not print the corresponding name. Instead, I got "d" for the employee[mini_idx] and "a" for employee[maxi_idx] which is parsing(?) my last added name to the list "dean" of only 3 employees. I verified this by using 3 employees and making the final name "john" and came back with "j" and then "h" How can I correspond the employee with the salary?

Comment: Whoops, see my update

Comment: Wow.. "name" that makes sense. I think I just had one of those "Shoulda had a v8" moment. Thank you very much, it works!

Comment: Excellent. Feel free to accept the answer if it works...